# Differences in certificate verification between ssl libraries

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, openssl, x.509

I've been playing with x509 certificates to better understand them and I've hit a strange issue which makes me think I have a misunderstanding. Initially I tested everything with libressl 2.8.3 and things work as expected, however when testing against openssl 1.1.1d things fall apart.

First I've created a root key and certificate with

```
libressl ecparam -out root.pem -name secp384r1 -genkey
libressl req -new -key root.pem -out root.csr
libressl x509 -in root.csr -out root.crt -req -signkey root.pem -days 30
```

then the intermediate

```
libressl ecparam -out inter.pem -name secp384r1 -genkey
libressl req -new -key inter.pem -out inter.csr
libressl x509 -in inter.csr -out inter.crt -req -signkey root.pem -days 30
```

and a leaf

```
libressl ecparam -out leaf.pem -name secp384r1 -genkey
libressl req -new -key leaf.pem -out leaf.csr
libressl x509 -in leaf.csr -out leaf.crt -req -signkey inter.pem -days 30
```

The issue I'm hitting is that libressl will verify the intermediate cert while openssl will not

```
>>> libressl verify -CAfile root.crt inter.crt
inter.crt: C = US, ST = CA, L = SF, O = Inter
error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate
OK
>>> openssl verify -CAfile root.crt inter.crt
C = US, ST = CA, L = SF, O = Inter
error 18 at 0 depth lookup: self signed certificate
error inter.crt: verification failed
```

Am I missing something or is openssl exposing that I have a misunderstanding of x509 certs and libre/openssl? Similarly validating the leaf cert with a bundle of the root and intermediate succeeds with libressl and fails with openssl.

Edit:

Thanks to Mike Ounsworth pointing out the issue. My intermediate cert was being generated as a self signed cert using the

```
openssl x509 -req -signkey root.pem -days 30 -in inter.csr -out inter.crt
```

command. Which resulted in a certificate which read

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number: 14260606495133371304 (0xc5e7da0d280d8ba8)
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA1
        Issuer: C=US, ST=CA, L=SF, O=Test, OU=Test, CN=Intermediate
        Validity
            Not Before: Jan 21 20:45:34 2020 GMT
            Not After : Feb 20 20:45:34 2020 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=CA, L=SF, O=Test, OU=Test, CN=Intermediate
```

Swapping the command above to

```
openssl x509 -req -days 30 -in inter.csr -CA root.crt -CAkey root.pem -CAcreateserial -out inter.crt
```

Resulted in a certificate with the issuer set to root.

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number: 14926915319265390371 (0xcf270e658d266f23)
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA1
        Issuer: C=US, ST=CA, L=SF, O=Test, OU=Test, CN=Root
        Validity
            Not Before: Jan 21 20:51:07 2020 GMT
            Not After : Feb 20 20:51:07 2020 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=CA, L=SF, O=Test, OU=Test, CN=Intermediate
```

The intermediate cert now passes verification

However on verification the leaf certificate I get an error with

```
❯❯❯ libressl verify -verbose -CAfile root.crt -untrusted inter.crt leaf.crt
leaf.crt: C = CA, ST = CA, L = SF, O = Test, OU = Test, CN = Intermediate
error 24 at 1 depth lookup:invalid CA certificate
OK
```

To Answer my own question. I had to add the CA:true x509v3 extension to my intermediate certificate. This gave me the cert generation line

```
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 30 -in inter.csr -CA root.crt -CAkey root.pem -extfile extensions.txt -out inter.crt
```

With `extensions.txt` reading

```
 basicConstraints=critical,@bs_section

 [bs_section]

 CA=true
 pathlen=1
```

copied directly from
https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man5/x509v3_config.html

I'm unclear about what `critical` means as openssl simply states `If critical is present then the extension will be critical.` on their man page, but whatever.

Comment: It looks to me like both are throwing a `error 18 at 0 depth lookup`, and for some reason openssl considers that a fatal error while libressl does not. If you posted a text dump / pretty print of the root and inter certs, that might help us spot the problem.

Comment: You've omitted to show us the interactive part of the `req` command. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19738223/1907046) suggests that you might get this error if the root and intermediate have the same DN / CN, which is not allowed. (x509 is full of pesky little rules, and it often takes me a few tries to generate valid certs with openssl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pending more info in the question, I would guess that when you invoke the `req` command, you are using the same Distinguished Name (DN) for all certs. If so, the error that you're seeing on both openssl and libressl

```
error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate
```

is because the SubjectDN and IssuerDN are the same, so openssl expects the cert to be self-signed (ie signed with its own key). As suggested by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19738223/1907046).

RFC 5280 (the X.509 spec) says:

> Name chaining is performed by matching the issuer
>      distinguished name in one certificate with the subject name in a CA
>      certificate.

Comment: X.509 is a complicated spec and it often takes me several tries to generate a valid cert chain in openssl.

Comment: This does seem to be the case. I am putting CNs in as `Root` `Intermediate` and `Leaf`, but looking at the intermediate cert I'm seeing a match in subject and issuer. `Issuer: C=US, ST=CA, L=SF, O=Test, OU=Test, CN=Intermediate` and `Subject: C=US, ST=CA, L=SF, O=Test, OU=Test, CN=Intermediate`